# Doctrine many-to-many relationship select

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following data model:
I have categories which can have posts. Those articals can have many categories they are in.
NowIi want to select all articles from one category.

What I tried so far is:

```
 $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('c, p')
        ->from('...Blog\Category', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.posts', 'p')
        ->where('c.id = :id')
        ->orderBy('p.created', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter(':id', $catId);
```

Now i want to feed this query into a pagination bundle whoch expects to get a list of all posts.

The problem is, that this query returns a "category" object.

How can I just get the posts from a category?

I'm using Symfony 2 with the KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: instead of selecting both c(category) and p(post) why not just select p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is wrong. When you do a left join it selects rows from the left table. Just flip them.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('c, p')
        ->from('c.posts', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('...Blog\Category', 'c')
        ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
           $qb->expr()->eq('c.id', ':id'),
           $qb->expr()->eq('p.category_id', 'c.id')
         )
        ->orderBy('p.created', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter(':id', $catId);
```

Comment: But isn't that very slow to first join all entries and then select the ones which should be returned?

Comment: I don't think it does it the way you say.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to make another query where you select Posts of a specific category.

The alternative - and what you're asking for - is probably to work with ArrayCollections: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#initializing-collections
So you're able to get all Posts from your Category object.